# Add textures to .pack file. in libgdx

Tags: libgdx

So I want to know if there is a way to add textures in an already created .pack file instead of repacking all the textures again with the new additions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Atlases support paging, basically, you append a new page to the atlas.

Add a blank line to the pack file and then start the next atlas.  Either pack the next page and copy/paste the file to the end or write it manually.

This line is where it starts a new page:
https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/blob/master/gdx/src/com/badlogic/gdx/graphics/g2d/TextureAtlas.java#L110

Answer (score 0):

What I like to do during development is repacking all raw images each time I run the project. This off course can be commented out to safe time but for my personal projects packing rarely exceeds a couple of seconds. So as long as you do not change existing filenames all changes and additions will be pushed trough.

I usually create a separate folder within the project folder called images. Here I put all my images, if I want to have my packs categorized I create additional folders to pack separately. Then in the desktop module I add the following lines:

```
    Settings settings = new Settings();
    //settings.XXXXXX change packer settings to your preferences.

    //Since I set my working folder to android/assets I need to go down 2
    //folders to get into the root of the project and access images.
    //Likewise, for output I already start in my assets folder.
    //So setting the path might differ depending on your working/asset folder.
    TexturePacker.process(settings, "../../images/tileset01", "tilesets", "tileset01");
```

In the above scenario I have put all my separate images for `tileset01` in the folder `project\images\tileset01` and they will be packed into `project\android\assets\tilesets` as `tileset01.png` and `tileset01.pack`.